# Using Objects as arrays in Java

Tags: java

I want to create an array object of a class named User, when i click a checkbox a new object of that class should be created.When i run and click the checkbox error :
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

```
public class User
{
    public int user_amt;
    int user_location;
    String user_name;
    private boolean user_isSelected()
    {
            return true;
    }
    int user_id;
User()
{
    user_amt = 0;
    user_location = 0;
    user_name = "NUL";
    user_id = 0;
    user_isSelected();

}
```

}

```
class main()
{
 int users_active;
 private void jCheckBox1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

        users_active++;
        User[] user = new User();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try with:

```
User[] user = new User[5];
user[0] = new User();
```

Comment: That worked thank you so much, can you explain me how these lines work and what was the problem with my code.

Comment: Each object in java must be created (allocated). This is done using `new` keyword. To create instance of class `MyClass` you have to say `new MyClass()`. To create array of `MyClass` you have to say first `new MyClass[n]` to create array of `n` elements, then create and assign individual elements using `myarray[i] = new MyClass()`

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you are creating an array of references, but each of those references must be created on the heap.

so `User[] user = new User[5]` <- creates 5 references

`user[0] = new User();` <- creates 1 object of type `User` on the heap and assigns it to `user[0]` reference.

Answer (score 0):

The following is plain wrong.

```
User[] user = new User();
```

`User[] user` is an array of User, whereas `new User()` is a single instance of User.

Secondly, you need to abandon all that you know about visual basic when you code in C++, C# or Java, where you need to pre-allocate the size of the array before adding members to it.

You cannot do

```
User[] users;
for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
  users[i] = new User();
}
```

You have to

```
User[] users = User[10];
for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
  users[i] = new User();
}
```

or

```
User[] users = {
  new User(), new User(), new User(), new User(), new User(), 
  new User(), new User(), new User(), new User(), new User()
}
```

That is why you should consider using an ArrayList, because they are expandable. While Arrays are not expandable.

```
List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
  users.add(new User());
}
```

To get the 5th member,

```
users.get(4);
```